# two div in the same line one div center and the other div to the right

Tags: html, css

I have situation like

```
                         CustomerInformation                               button
```

the above is output i want

```
    <div id="headerCustomer">   


<h:outputText  style="font-size: 18px;font-weight:bold;"  value="CustomerInformation " ></h:outputText>


<input type="button"></input>

    </div>
```

what could be the css for the above to achieve.

Comment: What is the language used? What does `<h:outputText />` tag mean?

Comment: using xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" html tags can be accessed using h variable.

Comment: @mdepolli Its not big deal to do that My problem is if i zoom in or zoom out the alignment is not sinking up with the rest of the contents thats why I have posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<div id="headerCustomer"> 
<div style="float:left; padding-left:100px;" >
<h:outputText  style="font-size: 18px;font-weight:bold;"  value="CustomerInformation">    </h:outputText>
</div>
<div style="float:right" ><input type="button" /></div>
```

Comment: input tag naver close </input>  is this <input type="submit">

Comment: thanks sujanth but when I zoom in or zoom out it is not moving according to other elements which i placed according to percentages.

Comment: @satish You can use '%' value instead of static values. Ex: 50%

Answer (score 1):

.................................

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ETRBRKPI)***

Hi now do this easily

as like this

**Css**

```
    #headerCustomer{
    background:red;
      position:relative;
    }
    .cntr{
    font-size: 18px;font-weight:bold;
      background:green;
      display:block;
      width:500px;
      margin:0 auto
    }
.inbg{
position:absolute;top:0; right:0;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="headerCustomer">   


<h:outputText   value="CustomerInformation" class="cntr">Hello the the text here</h:outputText>


<input type="button" value="submit" class="inbg">

    </div>
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/ETRBRKPI)***

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking like this :- http://tinkerbin.com/jLXcBKTL

**HTML**

```
<div id="headerCustomer">   
<h:outputText value="CustomerInformation " >Customer Information</h:outputText>
<input type="button" value="submit"></input>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#headerCustomer {
background:red;
text-align:center;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight:bold; 
}
input[type=button] { 
  float: right;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;  
}
```